# Am I expecting too much of one database table?

Tags: database, database-design, modeling

I'm working on a proprietary feedback application. I have a table named *topics* that I will to use to store suggestions, questions, and problems.

```
topics [ id, user_id, title, content, type[suggestion, question, problem] ]
```

I can easily store this data in one table using a `type` column to distinguish between the three different topic types.

However, there's another wrinkle: Each topic has its own responses too, and responses are very similar to the topics themselves. I'm tempted to store them in the same table as well. So now I have `type (suggestion, question, problem)` and `subtype (topic, response)`.

Am I asking too much of my topics table? Should I split my data into separate tables? I'm using Postgres and Rails for this particular project.

Best way to visualise is to compare it to StackoverFlow. SO stores questions and answers in the same `posts` table. Now suppose instead of only questions SO decided to allow suggestions and problems. Would they still use the same table?

Comment: I think one table with type is the best approach. If the table gets big, then we can partition based on type and in the object space (assuming that you use OOP), we can have three different object representing the same table, based on type. Most ORM will allow us to do this.

Comment: But I have two types: I have the topic type, and then a topic response. So essentially I have a type and a sub type. But what should be considered a type? Topic and response, or topic types (suggestions, problems, etc...)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why `topics` table has a `user_id` column. From pure design perspective I would create a separate table for `responses`. Further, you don't know what design changes you'll have to implement in the future and having a good separation between topics and responses might make your life much easier.

Comment: @alfasin, the user_id column would store the owner of the topic.

Comment: Oh, I got it. I think, we can add another type called "Response" and use a column "Parent_ID" to map this suggestion to one of the topics.

Comment: @doc_180, precisely, which is making me question whether all this data belongs in the same table.

Comment: I recommend going with a `Parent_ID` and one table as mentioned by @doc_180. I've described it in [more detail below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12167883/1431750).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How often you'll want to query both topics and responses in one action? Maybe when searching, but sometimes you also want to search only topics or only responses. And how often you will need to query only one of them? Most of the time.

Go for two separate tables, you can use views with `UNION` clause if you want to use them together. Also at the application level you can build inheritance model on top of relational database. Say `Post` object with `Topic` and `Response` subclasses. Some libraries like [hibernate](/questions/tagged/hibernate) will transparently translate query for *all posts that...` into two separate queries and union results together.

[Another approach](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.0.4/apache-openjpa-1.0.4/docs/manual/jpa_overview_mapping_inher.html) (also being one of the ways to deal with inheritance in relational store) would be to have... three tables! `Posts`, `Topics` and `Response`, the last two having foreign key to `Posts`. This way common columns are in one table and type-specific columns are separately.

Comment: Most of the time I will be querying in two ways: topics only, not responses, and then a particular type of topic (suggestion, problem, etc...) and its responses.

Comment: Imagine StackoverFlow as an example. They store Questions and Answers in the same table, called `posts`. Now suppose they added different things other than questions like suggestions and problems, would they still use the same table? Question becomes more specific with an underlying abstract class that is a parent to Questions and Problems, but distinct from answers.

Comment: When you say go for two separate tables, I assume you mean one for Topics and one for Responses?

Comment: @Mohamad: yes. Simple and effective. Of course this is just my subjective opinion.

Comment: @johnny, care to elaborate a little as to why?

Comment: @Mohamad I agree with Nurkiewicz's idea in his last paragraph.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the last paragraph. I thought the whole idea of inheritance was to use one table to store distinct classes that may have similarities in attributes and behaviour.

Comment: @Mohamad: actually you can implement inheritance in three ways. If you have `N` classes, depending on the approach, it'll take `1`, `N` or `N + 1` tables in total for mapping. Check the link I provided (it's about JPA, but the discussion is valid elsewhere)

Answer (score 1):

Keeping topics and responses in one table is better for forums. (A lot depends on the functionality you plan to have. Is it a forum or a news/articles/reviews site?)

Most forum frameworks use this design. Including SO as you mentioned. One distinction to make clear - note that what you are defining as "topic" is generally "post". So "responses" are also posts. What *other* frameworks call "topic" is the thread *info*.

- Here's an [image of phpBB's schema](http://internal.shirta.com/tech/phpbb3_tables.png) (warning, 1MB). Notice the `phpbb_posts` table with `post_text` and `topic_id` (where `topic_` is the title, forum id, view count, etc. but **not** the `post_text`).
- StackOverflow: The [`PostTypeId` in the `Posts` table](http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Understanding_the_StackOverflow_Database_Schema#Posts_Table) - *"1 is a question, 2 is an answer. Answers will have a ParentId field populated to link back to the question post."*
- See this related question and google for others: [How would you structure a forum's DB schema?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571192/how-would-you-structure-a-forums-db-schema)

You could query a post + responses using something like:

```
select t.id, t.user_id, t.title, t.content, t.type, t.parent_id,
       r.id, r.user_id, r.title, r.content, r.type, r.parent_id
from topics t
left join topics r on r.parent_id = t.id
where t.parent_id = 0 and t.id = <specific id>
```

The part you should separate is: If you want to show thread summaries like the stackoverflow Questions/Active/Newest pages; or forum index with latest topics, response, poster, etc. then maintaining a `thread_info` table would help for database performance, especially if you expect high vistor volume and/or many threads and posts.

> Now suppose instead of only questions SO decided to allow suggestions and problems. Would they still use the same table?

For `Suggestions` that depends. Look at [`comments` for example](http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Understanding_the_StackOverflow_Database_Schema#Comments_Table). Different table. The **nature(model) + functionality of comments is different enough** to be stored separately.

Taking another example: on news / reviews sites or like in wordpress, articles and their [responses would be stored separately](http://www.jayminkapish.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/03/wp_2.7.png) because of the same reasons. Articles would have relations to site authors, related articles, formatting, categories, etc. Responses would be threaded, possibly unformatted, etc.

Comment: Thanks! Great post. I forgot to add that assuming suggestions and are ideas were almost identical but for presentation, it would make sense to store them under the same table sometimes.

Comment: If they are identical then even more reason to keep them in the same table. You can always filter them out in your queries just by changing the `where` part or even in the server-side ruby after getting the query results.

Answer (score 0):

Use multiple tables here, you said it yourself:  there's another wrinkle: Each topic has its own respons**es** too

Multiple of anything usually requires another table.

I'd see it like this:
[TOPICS] [ topicID, user_id, title, content, type[suggestion, question, problem] ]

```
[SUGGESTION] [ suggID     <fields here>        *topicID ]
```

Note `topicID` as a foreign key in `[SUGGESTION]`